# Error Page for 500.100 not being hit in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, error-handling

I have the following in web.config of 'localhost' in IIS 7. Localhost means the default website. Also, I have a number of asp pages under localhost in IIS 7. The problem is if I have the error page under root i.e. under localhost it all works fine and I see the error page if any error occurs, but when I specify the error page to be under the folder 'ErrorPages' then the error page never displays on error in asp. Any idea why I cannot use 'ErrorPages' folder for error page in this case?

```
  <httpErrors>
        <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="100" />
            <error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="100" path="/ErrorPages/CLASPError.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
         </httpErrors>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the physical ErrorPages folder exists and it contains your "CLASPError.asp" file.  Check that it has the same security as the root folder you were originally using.  Follow these steps:

- Delete the httpErrors element from the web.config.
- In IIS Manager select the Default Web Site.
- Open the Error Pages Feature.
- Select Edit Feature Settings... action.
- Select Custom error pages option, Click OK
- Select Add.. action
- Enter 500.100 in status code
- Select Execute a URL in this site
- Enter /ErrorPages/CLASPError.asp, Click OK